# Boolean values not being passed correctly from javascript function to action in ASP.NET MVC Controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to pass some boolean values from a javascript function to a ASP.NET MVC controller action, but boolean values are not being passed correctly, for example, $('#optChk_5').prop('checked') and $('#optChk_6').prop('checked') are returning false and the rest true. However, when I receive these values in the MVC controller action, all values are true. Why boolean values are not passed correctly from javascript function to action in MVC controller?

**Javascript code**:

```
   function onCheckboxesUpdate() {
        var b01= new Boolean( $('#optChk_4').prop('checked') );
        var b02= new Boolean( $('#optChk_5').prop('checked') );
        var b03= new Boolean( $('#optChk_6').prop('checked') );
        var b04= new Boolean( $('#optChk_7').prop('checked') );

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("UpdateCheckBoxes", "MyController", new { @area = "MyArea" })',
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                'Id': @Model.Id,
                'b01': Boolean(b01),
                'b02': Boolean(b02),
                'b03': Boolean(b03),
                'b04': Boolean(b04)
            },
            dataType: "html",
            async: false,
            success: function (actionResponse) {
            }
        });
    }
```

**Action in MVC Controller**:

```
    public ActionResult UpdateCheckBoxes(int Id,
                                         bool b01,
                                         bool b02,
                                         bool b03,
                                         bool b04)
    {
         // Do something
    }
```

Comment: I removed the explicit parsing inside the ajax call and got the correct data in the backend

Comment: http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/the-difference-between-boolean-objects-and-boolean-primitives-in-javascript.html